# Disable SSL certificate validation in Haskell `req` library

Tags: haskell, https, haskell-req

How to disable SSL certificate validation when using the Haskell `req` library? Similar to `curl -k`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import Network.Connection (TLSSettings (TLSSettingsSimple))
import Network.HTTP.Client (newManager)
import Network.HTTP.Client.TLS (mkManagerSettings)
import Network.HTTP.Req

main = do
  myManager <- newManager $ mkManagerSettings (TLSSettingsSimple True False False) Nothing
  let httpConfig = def { httpConfigAltManager = Just myManager }
  runReq httpConfig $ do
    req POST -- ...
```

Comment: what is `def` ?  `def` should be `defaultHttpConfig`